# Windows Phone 8 Offline Developer Registration

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, app-store, xap

I have a Lumia 520 with Windows Phone 8 installed.

I'm a C# developer, but I have a problem, when I go to register my phone for a Microsoft Developer Account, or when I go to connect my device to the App Store I get an error saying:

> I'm Sorry this Service is Not available for your Region.

I know I am getting this issue because I live in Cuba. My question is: **how do I can install a .XAP app without registering my phone?** Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Thanks jsve for the Grammar Correction.

Answer (score 0):

To install .xap files from your phone's SD card

1. Insert an SD card that contains one or more .XAP files into your phone.
2. In the App list, tap Store Store Tile.
3. Tap More More icon, then tap Install local apps. (If you're running an earlier version of Windows Phone, look for the SD card option instead.)

**Note**
If you've just inserted the SD card or added the .XAP files, you might need to wait a few minutes before you can access your SD card from the Store.

4. Select the apps you want, then tap Install.
5. Installed apps appear in the App list. Depending on the specific app or game, you'll be able to use them as follows:

   - Free apps and games can be used immediately.
   - Paid apps and games that have a trial will be available as a trial version that you can purchase later.
   - Paid apps and games without a trial must be purchased before you can use them.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to install the apps. Right now I'm in the Collage when I went home I will do It. Thanks Again.

Comment: When I Try this solution my phone still asking me for an Internet Connection to the store. And  I have the same problem again. Did Exist an 3rd Party or Non Microsoft Store option? Thank By the way for help me.